# anchor does not wrap around li. why?

Tags: html, css

I have following html and css code in which I want `<a>` tag to wrap around `<li>` tags using css.

here is [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qrXWQ/)

html

```
<section class="row header">
            <ul class="nav">
                <li class="navfirst"><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Resume</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Interests</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Work</a></li>
                <li class="navlast"><a href="#">Comments</a></li>
            </ul>
        </section>
```

css

```
.header .nav {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0; }
  .header .nav li {
list-style-type: none;
display: inline-block;
padding: 0.5% 1%;
border: 1px solid green; }
.header .nav li.navfirst {
  margin-right: 4%; }
.header .nav li.navlast {
  margin-left: 4%; }
.header .nav li a {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%; }
```

here is scss. above css is converted from scss file

```
.nav {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    li {
        list-style-type: none;
        display: inline-block;
        padding: 0.5% 1%;
        border: 1px solid green;
        &.navfirst {
            margin-right: 4%;
        }
        &.navlast {
            margin-left: 4%;
        }
        a {
            display: block;
            text-decoration: none;
            border: 1px solid red;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How is the a supposed to wrap around the li when it's the child-element?

Comment: Its hard to tell what you actually want... The `<li>` is wrapping the `<a>` tag. so what exactly do you mean when you say you want the `<a>` tag to wrap the `<li>` tag? Do you want the `<a>` tag to be bigger then the `<li>`? As it stands right now I gave +1 to @devundef because that seems like what you are asking for...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the padding from the `li` tags:

```
...
display: inline-block;
padding: 0.5% 1%;   <-- padding: 0
border: 1px solid green; 
...
```

http://jsfiddle.net/qrXWQ/1/

Add padding to the `a`:

```
.header .nav li a {
     display: block;
     text-decoration: none;
     border: 1px solid red;
     padding: 5px; 
}
```

Remove the `width: 100%` and `height: 100%` from the rule above, otherwise the padding will mess up the layout...

http://jsfiddle.net/qrXWQ/2/

In the rule above the percent unit will not work because it has no base width/height to apply the % to. You have 3 options: 1) leave the padding in the LI, 2) put the padding in the `a` with a unit other than % (`em` fits well here), or 3) use media queries to set a diferent padding for each screen size.

Comment: but I want to add padding. how can I add padding? I add it to `a tags` but it is not working

Comment: Hum, you'll get the same effect if you add padding to the `a` tags and leave the `li`s with 0.

Comment: @al0neevenings why you want padding to you LI.

Comment: I want to add background images. and also to make these my menu a bit more like rectangle.

Comment: yes it is ok but what If I want to use `percentage` like this `5%`. Then it does not work. I want to use `%` because I am making a fluid layout which works on all screens including mobile phones.